# Intergration $\dfrac{1}{x}\exp\left[i(Ax^2+Bx+C)\right]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, numerical-methods

I need to calculate the integral:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\dfrac{1}{x}\exp\left[i(Ax^2+Bx+C)\right]dx$$

I guess complex analysis is suitable for this integral, but I still have no ideas which kinds of trick I can use.
Does anyone has ideas?
Thank you!

---

Actually, I am not sure whether it is convergent or not. The original formula is:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}K_{1}(x)\exp\left[i\left(Ax^2+Bx+C\right)\right]dx$$
I try to numerically evaluate:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}
(K_{1}(x)-\dfrac{1}{x})\exp\left[i\left(Ax^2+Bx+C\right)\right]dx$$
and then evaluate this term analytically:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\dfrac{1}{x}\exp\left[i\left(Ax^2+Bx+C\right)\right]dx$$

How can I prove whether it is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Why do you think it is a convergent integral? $x=0$ looks as a non-integrable singularity to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you for your comment. I have updated the question. Actually, I am not sure whether it is convergent or not? How could I prove it?

Comment: Is $K_1(x)$ the Bessel function?

Comment: @kennytm yes, it is modified bessel function of second kind.